# What's the potential energy in a system of magnets?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, potential-energy

I am trying to model a 3d pendulum consisting of a magnetic bob attached to a string. If the pendulum is allowed to swing over a structure of permanent magnets, it will display complex motion ([here](https://youtu.be/yQeQwwXXa7A) a YT video).

The point is to study the dynamics so I need to compute the magnetic potential energy that the moving magnet of the pendulum would have. I was thinking of using $$U=-\mathbf{m}\cdot\mathbf{B}$$ with $\mathbf{m}$ being the magnetization of the moving magnet and $\mathbf{B}$ being the total magnetic field at the center of the magnet. What do you think? Can someone confirm that this makes sense?

Comment: $U$ is not enough as you have moving magnetic moments you have to include dynamical effects and this can be quite complex as that produces additional electromagnetic fields (which induce currents in the magnets that also produce other magnetic fields). You will have to solve Maxwell's equations in matter to calculate the fields.

Comment: I see... It is certainly not trivial. Thank you very much for your comment Mauricio!